# How can I make Parcel shipping cost take priority over Large Letter?

Tags: shipping

Our shop sells over 150 products ranging in weight from 2g to 50kg. Some of the lightweight items are Large letter and cost £1 to post to UK address whilst others, although still lightweight, are bulky and therefore categorised as small parcel: these cost £3 or so to post. All products are categorised correctly (Large Letter Post enabled? either Yes or No). When customer purchases product in Large Letter category, correct postage is shown, but when they continue shopping and buy other small packet items (costing £3 to post), the postage remains at £1. If the Large Letter item is removed from the basket, the postage then reverts to the correct £3. Meanbee cannot assist and our web developer says that there are no extensions available to fix this problem. Could the Shipping rules or other features be adjusted so that parcel postage takes priority over Large Letter when customers buy both items?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with Magento's base shipping (but I might be wrong). If you have a dev environment, you should give a try at OwebiaShipping2, it's quite complicated to set the shipping methods right, but they have quite a wide range of options.